# RANK over sum of values from multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

so this is my table:

```
S_ID | PHY | CHEM | MATHS | BIO |
_____________________________________
S01  | 100 | 100  | 100   | 100 |
S02  | 90  | 90   | 80    |  90 |
S03  | 80  | 76   | 45    |  40 |
S04  | 70  | 91   | 71    |  65 |
S05  | 70  | 99   | 88    |  67 |
S06  | 40  | 56   | 55    |  88 |
S07  | 10  | 55   | 62    |  88 |
```

I need to add all the marks and then give ranks and percentiles to all the student ids based on the total.

Any help on how to do that ? i am unable to use the `RANK()` function over the total.. i  am using `(PHY+CHEM+BIO+MATHS)` as `TOTAL` and then choosing rows where `ROWNUM < whatever rank i need`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT S_ID, (MATHS+BIO+CHEM+PHY) AS TOTAL FROM MARKS ORDER BY TOTAL DESC )
WHERE ROWNUM < 4;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use the `rank()` function on the total:

```
select S_ID, (MATHS+BIO+CHEM+PHY) AS TOTAL,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MATHS+BIO+CHEM+PHY DESC) as rank
FROM MARKS
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC;
```

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by percentile, but the other analytic functions should work similarly.

EDIT:  I would do the "percentile" using explicit logic.  Something like:

```
select s.*
from (SELECT S_ID, (MATHS+BIO+CHEM+PHY) AS TOTAL,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MATHS+BIO+CHEM+PHY DESC) as rank,
             COUNT(*) OVER () as num
      FROM MARKS
    ) s
WHERE num * 60/100 <= rank
      ORDER BY TOTAL DESC;
```

There may be other functions such as that you can also use for this purpose.

Comment: Percentile can be accomplished with `NTILE(100)` instead of `RANK()`.

Comment: @BaconBits, NTILE is not available in ORACLE

Comment: @RADAR Yes, it is.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions101.htm

Comment: @Gordon : Thanks a ton !! your query for the RANK() function is working just fine !

Comment: The percentile query would be done using this: iv made a slight modification to your code here *thanks again*

Answer (score 0):

Select S_ID, (MATHS+BIO+CHEM+PHY) AS TOTAL,

```
   TO_CHAR(PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MATHS+BIO+CHEM+PHY), '9.9999')*100 as PERCENTILE
```

FROM MARKS

ORDER BY TOTAL DESC;